How to populate an enum dynamically within a Roadie/Backstage template (JSON Schema)
I have a template property that allows users to select from a list of environments, but the permissible options vary depending on business domain.
I have looked-up the list of environments from a call earlier in the template, let's say stored as array myEnvironments.
How can I use my array object rather than hardcoding the enum values?
properties:
  envs:
    title: Select environments
    type: array
    uniqueItems: true
    ui:widget: checkboxes
    items:
    type: string
    enum: [dev, test, stage, prod] # hardcoded values

I've tried the typical variable replacement syntax, like: ${{myEnvironments}}
{{myEnvironments}}
As well as various string/array manipulations. No luck.
There is always the possibility of a custom plugin but for something so simple, there has to be a better way.
I've trawled through the JSON Schema docs.. there's a lot in there which is promising, but nothing seems to fit this problem.
Surely this is a common use-case?
All help appreciated!

A custom component will be necessary. The json schema UI doesn't handle dependencies between fields very well

Can I ask how you looked up myEnvironments in the first place?
